# Not a 50/50 probability in coinflip

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, computational-mathematics, monte-carlo

I have the following coinflip game:

We flip a coin arbitrary many times(finite).

For every pair of tails, tails twice in a row, A gets a point. While for every pair of tails-heads, tails followed by heads, B gets a point. If it is heads-heads or heads-tails neither get a point. The winner is the player with the most points when they stop.

I have simulated 3 different lengths 47,100 and 1000 flips, each game was simulated 100000 and took the probability of A or B winning. (number of times one won/number of simulations). With tails being 0 and heads 1.

For each length I got that B had a slightly higher chance of winning than A. But I end up with the two questions:

1. Why is this so, what is there a proof/probability theoretical explanation?
2. When i run my code there is a bigger difference in A's prob. of winning between 47 flips and 100 flips(0.03) then 100 and 1000(0.005). What is the explanation of this(I though high number of simulations should avoid big differences w.r.t. the game length).

Comment: What does "stop" mean? given that we have infinitely many tosses....

Comment: So that we can have a winner, the length of each game should not change that B has a slight advantage.

Comment: So, infinitely many means $N$  times for some fixed $N$?

Comment: No, I think that it would not matter if the length of the game is finite or infinite, but to simulate I must have some finite length.

Comment: If the game is infinite, then both players will score infinitely many points (with probability $1$) so neither will win. I really think you mean $N$ for some finite $N$.  Of course, part of the problem can be to show that $B$ has a persistent advantage for all $N$.

Comment: Yes I agree, there should be finite N. I will edit the post.

Comment: If the coin is fair then 10,000 heads in a row is possible. So you shouldn't expect simulations to give you enough information as to real advantages. Computers don't generate random number either. They're pseudorandom which is only approximately random but is actually deterministic. So you may simply be using the same numbers repeatedly in your simulations rather than actually randomness.

Comment: Does TTT count as two pairs of tails ?

Comment: Not quite correct, since you run the games so many times and use the average of the results. You take into account that that would happen, so that is not an explanation.

Comment: Yes TTT does count as two pair of tails.

Comment: Informally:  Claim is true for $N=3$.  If the first toss is $H$, $B$ has an advantage by induction.  If the first toss is $TH$ then $B$ has an advantage by induction.  So $B$ will have an inductive advantage with probability at least $\frac 34$.  Thus you just need to argue that starting out with a string of Tails isn't a complete disaster for $B$ (weighted by the probability of that start).

Comment: Should add:  this question was asked fairly recently on this site, though I have been unable to track down the duplicate.  Perhaps it's been deleted?  If memory serves, it did not get a satisfactory answer (but maybe I am misremembering).

Comment: Maybe I should try math.overflow?

Comment: @PinkElephants No, the standards there are rather stricter then less strict than here.

Comment: @lulu this is a question that was widely discussed on twittxr recently, e.g. [**here**](https://twitter.com/littmath/status/1769044719034647001).

Comment: I don't get the down/close votes.  As I mentioned, I think it should be made clear that the number of tosses is given by a parameter $N$, but aside from that, the question is clear, and simulating the thing is certainly a sensible start.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Are you suggesting that 100,000 simulations isn't enough to get accurate results for this problem, or that Monte Carlo simulation is inherently not a useful method?

Comment: @user6247850 Monte Carlo is useful but it has limits and you should be aware of them when interpreting results. Randomness can have streaks and computers aren't always random. That can lead to the perception of bias that doesn't actually exist. In fact, a lack of streaks often indicates that the data isn't actually random.  For example in forensic accounting a lack of streaks can indicate someone has changed the data and is useful for detecting fraud.